# Redefined AND operator in Prolog

Tags: prolog, operator-overloading, operators, operator-keyword

I want to redefine AND operator in SWI-Prolog . But I do not know how to do it.
I tried the following definition:

```
a & b = b & a
```

However, it is reported as recursive and does not work.
Wish people give me suggestions.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not clear what you mean by redefining the AND operator. And in Prolog is (',')/2 ; you cannot change its definition.

Comment: @false This is incorrect. See answer below.

Comment: @aBathologist: OP asks about redefining (**re**-defining) the AND operator. And, as also sharky observes, the and operator in Prolog is `(',')/2`. Apart from that, it is pointless to do that.

Comment: @false @false There must be some miscommunication. Here's where I'm coming from: §4.25 of the SWI-Prolog manual begins, "Operators are defined to improve the readability of source code. For example, without operators, to write 2*3+4*5 one would have to write +(*(2,3),*(4,5)). In Prolog, a number of operators have been predefined. All operators, except for the comma (,) can be redefined by the user." An operator is syntactic sugar. Redefining an operator means changing the flavor. It is only about how code *looks*. `A & B` is, for me, much less ambiguous than `A , B`. So how is that pointless?

Comment: @ErikKaplun: The question applies to any Prolog, so Prolog specific tags are not helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You could define an operator in SWI-Prolog using [`op/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=op/3), such as by adding the following to your program:

`:- op(1000, xfy, user:(&)).`

Note that the precedence level (`1000`) and type (`xfy`) are the same as that for the conjunction operator which is already defined in SWI-Prolog (i.e., see [`','/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%274.24%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/operators.html%27%29%29)).

Then, once declared, you can define the semantics of `&` as follows:

`'&'(A,B) :- A, B.`

Together, these two definitions will permit you to use `&` in-line as a replacement for `,` to mean conjunction in the program which incorporates them.

Comment: Thanks! Your explanation made clear the specifics of operator definitions which I hadn't quite grasped.

Comment: A pleasure, I'm glad this answer is still helping others! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can "define" `and` as follows:

```
and(t,X,X) :- bool(X).
and(f,X,f) :- bool(X).
bool(t).
bool(f).
```

The third argument is the result of the conjunction of the first and the second argument.

Of course, this is just an exercise, but indeed it is hard to answer your question as it is not very clear what your question is all about.

Comment: This answer is, as far as I can tell, completely irrelevant to the question, which is quite clear and well answered by sharks. It might be a good idea to delete it.

Comment: @aBathologist: This is a possible valid answer to a not very clear question.

Comment: @false Rereading it, I can see what you mean. I still think that the question is quite clear, insofar as he asks how to **re**-define the AND *operator* but not how to define a new function and/3. However, I can definitely see how this answer provides useful information on the basic conceptual structure of AND.  And I agree that my recommendation for deletion isn't very helpful.